# What is the cause of "No instance for (Show (Int -> Int)) arising from a use of `print'" error when trying to give function a type in Haskell?

Tags: haskell, typing

Error came up when writing this:

```
definition x = x
definition :: Int -> Int
```

Comment: You can not show `definition` itself, since that is a function, you can show the result of `definition 5`. The reason you here got an error is because you did not define the function in a multi-line statement, and furthermore the signature should be written before the definition.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem, there is actually no requirement for the signature to precede the definition (I just learned).  It's just highly unconventional to do otherwise

Answer (score 6):

You are entering your code in GHCi, line by line.

The first line defines your function.

The second line asks it to be printed, which can not be done.

Don't write your code line by line in GHCi. Write it in a file, and then load it in GHCi.

Answer (score 6):

You here first defined a function `definition x = x`. In the second line, you then have an expression `definition :: Int -> Int`. But a function is not an instance of `Show`, and thus the interpreter can not print the function.

It looks however like your second line is the signature you want to add to the function. You can use `:{` and `:}` to write multi-line statements, like:

```
Prelude> :{
Prelude| definition :: Int -> Int
Prelude| definition x = x
Prelude| :}
```